# Why does DEFAULT INCOMING DENY not stop Firefox from working?

Tags: firewall, ufw

If UFW is actually not an application layer firewall but a "interface to iptables",
how can it be if I have by `DEFAULT INCOMING DENY` and `OUTGOING ALLOW` setting that ANY internet application is working?

Especially Deluge and Transmission the torrent clients are working.  Why?

I mean firefox does receive traffic on port 80 for example (INCOMING!).

To me that would prove that actually the UFW is not working at all?

Comment: Your examples are all outgoing connections. No wonder they works, you allow that... (as is normally sane).
Now, if I try to `ssh` to your PC or try to connect to your web **server**, my outgoing (which is your incoming) connection will be denied.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, incoming connections are only classified as connections that originate from without your network. Firefox starts a connection from *within* your network, so it doesn't count as an "incoming connection".

If you want to disable internet just take the interface you are using down:

```
sudo ifconfig <interface> down
```

You can find `<interface>` from a plain `ifconfig`:

```
ifconfig
```

If you're using ethernet it will be something similar to `eth` followed by a number. If you're using wireless it is usually either `wlan` followed by a number.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter your outgoing traffic with ufw with destination on port 80

```
sudo ufw deny out to any port 80
```